# What does it mean when a company schedules a interview with you and then cancels and says they are no longer interested?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

So I interviewed with a recruiter, everything went well. I was schedule for a second, technical interview, a couple of days later they abruptly cancelled the interview saying they decided to go with another candidate.

I have never had this experience before in my career.

Comment: It means you're not getting that job. Move on.

Comment: It means they decided to hire another candidate?  Happens.

Comment: Hey, at least they told you something at all.

Comment: It does not mean that you did anything wrong or bad. Just forget about that company, and move on. There are tons of other good companies that you can apply for, and you should prepare for the interviews with these companies for the new jobs. Good luck.

Comment: @Job_September_2020, thank you

Comment: @mxyzplk And they were professional enough to let you know of your current status.

Comment: @MichaelMcFarlane, I am breath taken how acceptable it is for my colleagues to accept executives engaging in what today is called ghosting. I need to audit an MBA class at my local university, see what the heck is going on.

Comment: @Daniel From the company's perspective, it saves time and prevents lawsuits. From the applicant's perspective, it's a nuisance, but ultimately not an actionable one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will never know. It's okay, and means nothing. Few options, you can pick any one to your liking:

1. they found your social network profile and didn't like it
2. they found social network profile of hiring manager, and they are not longer with the company
3. the project got cancelled, or budget got cut
4. they have been able to fill in the candidacy
5. hiring manager suddenly remembered that they already employ someone at that job

Comment: I am okay with either of those options as I have nothing but sensible posts out there, many academic actually, so if that bothered them, definitely not a good fit. I just found it odd, but a lot of modern companies are doing some odd things these days. I have been around long enough to remember there was no social media to check on and they reached out to me, I did not apply to them.

Comment: My only Twitter and Instagram is not tied to anything work related of mine, so God bless them if they hustled and somehow found it and were bothered by pictures of my veggie garden on Instagram.

Comment: The one that I always wondered about, I found out about a few years after being ghosted.  The company liked me, but the hiring manager quit with no notice.  The new team didn't have access to the old materials, and had no idea I had even talked to the company until I told them I'd already interviewed with them earlier.  It was a smaller company, but you never know the whole truth so don't think it is all about you or your actions.

Comment: @EdwinBuck, interesting, you said ghosted. I had an experience with another company where I interviewed with the CEO and it all went well and he just ghosted me afterwards. Sorry for obsessing, I just never saw this lack of professionalism my first decade in the world of work and now its all too common.

Comment: @Daniel It is common, I guess it is easier to just say nothing than to say no for many.  For others it might be that they are waiting on something that doesn't happen, and if it does it is far too late to ask if the candidate is still available.  I obsessed about the one above a bit, because I was clearly (from their account to me) the lead candidate and it was "expect a call next week" to nothing.  In my case, I was lucky to find out, but it's a small industry here, and after 20 years, you meet enough people.  Sometimes you get lucky and find out why.

Comment: @EdwinBuck, Thank you for sharing, it' s funny those comments that seem to express lack of professionalism as being okay among executive level officers are getting lots of upvotes, the acceptable levels of nihilism is breath taking, makes me want to audit a local MBA class, see what the heck is going on. With that said, I spoke to an accomplished CEO in the Bay Area who was told not to bother with an MBA she will learn as she goes, maybe that is the problem.

Comment: @Daniel - in my nearly four decades of work I have seen it often, it is common, it has been common, and it will continue to be common.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek, interesting, maybe its industry specific then. Its only been the last five years I have seen this, which is when I started working in tech, in finance and other fields, never saw it. In fact, at the end of every interview, i would get the average letter saying thank you for your time and in business school you are taught to send one right back. I stopped expecting those after my first year in tech, but I continued to send my own thank you for the interview letter, then I stopped sending mines. Heck, I used to wear suits to tech interviews, stopped that too.